# Did VB code wrote for Outlook 2000 still works for Outlook 2010?

Tags: vb6, outlook

Would need to upgrade the MS Outlook from 2000 to 2010, because the exchange server was upgraded to 2010. I suddenly found that I cannot connect to the exchange server with MS Outlook 2000. I got the admin and he said 2000 are not supported anymore.

We got a program written in VB 6.0 to automate massive(100+) emails sending. The program cooperates with Outlook client and send emails out through the exchange server.

Now I cannot even access the exchange mailbox, so a upgrade is necessary. But I wonder the VB code still valid? Are there compatible?

I have no idea of the detail of the code because it is left by one of our colleagues who had already left the company. There are some .bas .frm .frx .ocx and it cooperates with .mdb file.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874304/upgrading-vb6-code-from-outlook-2007-to-outlook-2010) you will need to change your Outlook object reference to `Outlook.Application.14`  from `Outlook.Application`. and of course there may be some other differences in the object models.